# Is it possible to nest a listview inside another one?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, listview

Using a C# 3.5 Winforms -

Is it possible to nest one listview inside another?  The idea is to a list of lists - The higher level list would be groupings and the lower level list would be the details.

**UPDATE:**

Nesting does not appear to be possible.  However using a FlowLayoutPanel I can add many listview controls into it and the panel takes care of automatic layout control.  Using grouping in each listview helps to identify what each list is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible (and certainly not recommended) to nest a WinForms listview inside another.  However you can enable grouping as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezh1batz.aspx).

Comment: I actually determined that a FlowLayoutPanel is what was needed.  The panel will automatically handle many listview controls.